# InOrder Binary Tree with Iterator toString()

Tags: java, list, binary-tree

I've written all the other stuffs like addChild(), insert(), etc but it seems like my toInorderToList() doesnt work. It should add all the elements off the tree into a List and afterwards i have to print out the list but i always get those errors java.util.ArrayList$Itr@70dea4e

my code snippets

```
    private List<BinaryTreeNode> toInorderList(){
    if(this.root == null){
        return new ArrayList<BinaryTreeNode>();
    }else{
        return toInorderList(this.root);
    }


}

private ArrayList<BinaryTreeNode> toInorderList(BinaryTreeNode node) {
    ArrayList<BinaryTreeNode> treelist = new ArrayList<BinaryTreeNode>();
    if(node.left !=null){
        toInorderList(node.left);
        treelist.add(node.left);    
    }
    treelist.add(this.root);
    if(node.right != null){
        toInorderList(node.right);
        treelist.add(node.right);
    }
    return treelist;

}
```

and toString() and iterator()

```
    public Iterator<BinaryTreeNode> iterator() {
    return toInorderList().iterator();
}    

public String toString() {
    return toInorderList().iterator().toString();

}
```

Comment: This code makes no sense... why are you ignoring the return value of the recursive invocations of `toInorderList`?

Comment: Can you please share the detailed exception/error that you are getting

Comment: You're probably wanting `treelist.addAll(toInorderList(node.left)); ...`

Comment: for your tree inorder/postorder/preorder traversal, copy the methods add an overload method that takes in the arraylist and when traversing simply do the arraylist add for the current node of the recursion.

Comment: i changed it to treelist.addAll(tiInorderList(node.left)); and treelist.addAll(tiInorderList(node.right)); now when i try to print it out it only prints out the root 4 times instead of the root + the 3 nodes that i added to the tree, i think i have to use the iterator for a for loop and add it one by one to the a string at toString()

Comment: @Lorenzo In your `toInorderList(BinaryTreeNode node)` method you have this line: `treelist.add(this.root);` which isn't doing what you think. You are adding the root of the tree to the list each time you call the function, as opposed to adding the node itself. Change it to `treeList.add(node)` instead. In addition to the other suggestions, it should behave like you expect.

Comment: `java.util.ArrayList$Itr@70dea4e` isn't an error, it's the `toString` of an iterator.

Comment: `toInorderList().iterator().toString()` is printing out the iterator, rather than the list.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in this code:

```
if(node.left !=null){
    toInorderList(node.left);
    treelist.add(node.left);    
}
treelist.add(this.root);
if(node.right != null){
    toInorderList(node.right);
    treelist.add(node.right);
}
```

the `toInorderList` function has a return value, so you need to use `treelist.addAll(toInorderList(node.left);`

Also, for memory efficiency, I'd probably use a single ArrayList outside your function, and just let each recursive call access it.

```
private List<BinaryTreeNode> toInorderList(){
    if(this.root == null){
        return new ArrayList<BinaryTreeNode>();
    }else{
        ArrayList<BinaryTreeNode> treeList = new ArrayList<BinaryTreeNode>();
        toInorderList(this.root, treeList);
        return treeList;
    }
}

private toInorderList(BinaryTreeNode node, ArrayList<BinaryTreeNode> treelist) {
    if(node.left !=null){
        toInorderList(node.left, treeList));
        treelist.add(node.left);    
    }
    treelist.add(this.root);
    if(node.right != null){
        toInorderList(node.right, treeList));
        treelist.add(node.right);
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't really make much sense to have an instance variable representing the list that your functions can access, and use the same list as a function parameter. It's not the most readable to start (you have local and instance variables with the same name), and it's unnecessary. You can eliminate the use of the instance variable altogether and have `toInorderList()` return a `List<BinaryTreeNode>` that was created locally.

Comment: Yeah, I meant to move the private declaration to be local after I fixed my code with an edit.

Comment: And the whole point of what I show there, was to remove the locally declared variable inside the `toInorderList` function to save memory. (Having an ArrayList for every stack frame can double memory usage for large trees.)

Comment: This is merely for concept though, since traversal of the tree nodes themselves is a more efficient/practical method to implement for an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard inorder traversal of a tree

```
  private void InOrder(AVLNode<T> T)
  {
        if(T == null){
           return;
        } 
        InOrder(T.left);
        System.out.print(T.item + ", ");
        InOrder(T.right);        
 }
```

create an overload and simply replace the system out with an arraylist add

```
  private void InOrder(AVLNode<T> T, ArrayList list)
  {
        if(T == null){
           return;
        } 
        InOrder(T.left, list);
        list.add(T.item);            
        InOrder(T.right, list);        
  }
```

It took me two min to modify my avl tree to accept this.
root is the head of the tree the instantiation of my tree in main.  I have an array of ints inside it

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>;
```

is my list instantiation.

```
root.InOrder(root);

root.InOrder(root, list);
```

both work just fine

Comment: may i ask what AVLNode is?

Comment: this is code from an avl tree I created for a class program, simply replace avlnode with your tree node

Comment: AVL is an algorithm for auto balancing tree creation

Comment: BTW tested and works all you have to do is call the inorder form the node with the list inside the call and the inorder will be in the list